# Access 2007 controlling users' permissions without VBA

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have a user community of about 100 with three being writers, the remainder are read only. Although I have two front end sessions, one reader and the other writer, and can control the latter through a `Form_Load()` event function, it fails if the user's macro security is set to high. The form opens regardless and an unauthorized user can edit records. Any way I can control which users can edit and which cannot by some means other than through VBA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask your network admin to grant either *read* or *modify* user specific rights to the folder that holds the backend file or to the backend file itself.

Comment: Yea, that's kind of where I was heading as well.

Comment: Ended up password protecting the writer's front end.